# I am not able to Drag and Drop in frames

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am not able to Drag and Drop in this frames, Below code i was used in Selenium Eclipse, But i get a
error, shown in this line "a.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();"
i am unable to Drag and Dropping. Please let me know what is the mistake in this.

```
 public class HandleFrames {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
            
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", 
                               "C:\\Users\\vinay\\Desktop\\driver\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/droppable/");
            driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[class='demoframe']")));
            Actions a = new Actions(driver);
            WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='draggable']"));
            WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='droppable']"));
            a.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();
            System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")).getSize());
            driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

There's a mismatch while switching to iframe. There's no iframe with class `demoframe` instead it is `demo-frame`. So making below changes should run your code successfully.

**Code :**

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[class='demo-frame']")));
```

**Update 1 :**

```
public class HandleFrames {
    
    static WebDriver driver;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\crusiepandey\\Desktop\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://jqueryui.com/droppable/");
        driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[class='demo-frame']")));
        Actions a = new Actions(driver);
        WebElement source = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='draggable']"));
        WebElement target = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[id='droppable']"));
        a.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();
        System.out.println("Action is successful");
        //System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")).getSize());
        driver.switchTo().defaultContent(); 
        driver.close();
    }
```

**Output :**

```
Starting ChromeDriver 90.0.4430.24 (4c6d850f087da467d926e8eddb76550aed655991-refs/branch-heads/4430@{#429}) on port 48759
Only local connections are allowed.
Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/security-considerations for suggestions on keeping ChromeDriver safe.
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
May 07, 2021 4:40:57 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Action is successful
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But i did a mistake in this above code,in my actual code this is only i wrote :                                                                   driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[class='demo-frame']")));

Comment: @DivyaGoud : If it resolved your query, please accept/upvote this answer so that this ticket will be closed.

Comment: but still error is shown in this below line                                                                                                                                a.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();

Comment: Comment this line `System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")).getSize());` and run it, works fine on my local machine

Comment: I get this in console 
`ChromeDriver was started successfully.
May 07, 2021 4:35:10 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Action is successful
PASSED: testSO

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Passes: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================`

Comment: Sorry for asking again, i did :commented the line what your shown above but still error is showing  this line   a.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();

Comment: Can you please send full code of the program

Comment: @DivyaGoud :Check out the update 1 section in my answer. Hope that helps

Comment: Yaaa but, i changed to this                                                                                                                            driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("iframe[class='demo-frame']")));   and i changed to this                                                                                           // System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")).getSize());  ,But sitll?

Comment: Error :Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.interactions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: move target out of bounds ----------------                                                                                                                        at seleniumsessions.HandleFrames.main(HandleFrames.java:24)                                                                                                                                                          This is 24th line   " a.dragAndDrop(source, target).build().perform();"

Comment: @DivyaGoud : Which selenium version you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Please try below locator to identify the iframe instead of iframe locator you have used, otherwise all other part of code is correct:

```
 driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"content\"]/iframe")));
```